# Activiti createTaskQuery().processInstanceId returns empty

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, transactions, activiti

I am using activiti with following maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>5.17.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-image-generator</artifactId>
    <version>5.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is activiti.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/TransactionManager"></property>
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- process engine configuration -->
    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.cdi.CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="dataSourceJndiName" value="asdfasdf" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="transactionsExternallyManaged" value="true" />
        <property name="transactionsExternallyManaged" value="false" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
        <property name="jdbcMaxActiveConnections" value="10" />
        <property name="jdbcMaxIdleConnections" value="10" />
        <property name="jdbcMaxCheckoutTime" value="20000" />
        <property name="jdbcMaxWaitTime" value="20000 " />
        <property name="history" value="audit" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Everything's works great but I could not get task with `taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId` after running `startProcessInstanceKey` in the same transaction.

Here is sample code.

```
@Inject
protected RuntimeService runtimeService;

@Inject
protected TaskService taskService;

....

ProcessInstance instance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(processDefinitionKey, getVariables());
Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(instance .getId).singleResult();
//task = null ?????.
```

Can you please help me to solve problem?

Comment: does your process contain any listener/service task before reaching to the task? your bpmn definition will be helpful

Comment: Actionally no there isn' t. Here is my sample bpmn file.[link](https://justpaste.it/680zm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(instance.getId).active().singleResult();`